# Is the Hadwiger-Nelson graph restricted to $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics

Consider the graph on $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ where two members of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ form an edge if and only if their distance is $1$. Is that graph bipartite? If not, what is its chromatic number? (It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) to be $\leq 7$.)

Comment: I think Theorem 7 of this source -- https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.186.4127&rep=rep1&type=pdf -- says this is a result of Woodall.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115435/hadwiger-nelson-problem-only-on-q-rationals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the chromatic number is $2$.  This result is due to Douglas R. Woodall, “Distances realized by sets covering the plane”, *J. Combinatorial Theory* **14** (1973), 187–200.  See also Alexander Soifer, *The Mathematical Coloring Book (Mathematics of Coloring and the Colorful Life of Its Creators)*, Springer (2009), §11.2.  See also my unpublished¹ note [“The Hadwiger-Nelson problem over certain fields”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.07023), esp. ¶1.6.

1. Because it turned out that (unbeknownst to me) most of the results contained therein were already obtained earlier in an (also unpublished) note by Eric Moorhouse, [“On the Chromatic Numbers of Planes”](https://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/chromatic.pdf), which is also relevant here.

Comment: I this graph connected? If so, this would mean that we must partition the members of $\mathbb Q^2$ into "white" and "black" points, as on a chess board. Is there some way to tell which is which?

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, the graph is not connected: it is the disjoint union of countably many classes, where $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ (in $\mathbb{Q}^2$) are in the same class when both $x-x'$ and $y-y'$ have $2$-adic valuation $v≥0$. (I think the classes thus divided are then connected.) Within the class of $(0,0)$, one color consists of those $(x,y)$ such that $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, and the other of those such that $x$ and $y$ have opposite parity, which is indeed like a chessboard. But you can independently choose the color mapping for each class.

Comment: Is there a way to tell which pairs belong to the class to which $(0,0)$ belongs?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've just done so: the class of $(0,0)$ (which, again, I think is connected) consists of those $(x,y)$ such that $v(x)≥0$ and $v(y)≥0$ (where $v$ is the $2$-adic valuation), and, among those, one color consists of those such that $v(x)>0$ XOR $v(y)>0$ whereas the other consists of those such that $v(x)=0$ and $v(y)=0$ or both are $>0$.

Comment: Thank you. $\qquad$